# How to prevent multiple instance creation by SHBrowseForFolder()?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am developing one application and i have added one button (CButton) which is calling SHBrowseForFolder() function. But the problem is that the button is still active and also it is letting me to click my parent window. Also i can click again and again that button and multiple browsing window are coming.

What i want to know that is there any way to use SHBrowseForFolder() in a DoModal() way, so that the control did not return to the parent window till user click that Ok/Cancel button of the folder browse window? I do not want to disable that button after clicking once or something like that.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

```
void CUtility::BrowseFolder(CWnd* pParentWnd, const CString& sTitle, CEdit& Edit)
{
  LPMALLOC pMalloc = NULL;
  ::SHGetMalloc(&pMalloc);

  TCHAR pBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};

  LPITEMIDLIST pidlRoot = NULL;

  BROWSEINFO bi;
  bi.hwndOwner = pParentWnd->m_hWnd;
  bi.pidlRoot = NULL;
  bi.pszDisplayName = pBuffer;
  bi.lpszTitle = sTitle;
  bi.ulFlags = BIF_USENEWUI;
  bi.lpfn = NULL;

  if((pidlRoot = ::SHBrowseForFolder(&bi)) == NULL)
    return;

  if(::SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlRoot, pBuffer))
    Edit.SetWindowText(pBuffer);

  if(pidlRoot)
    pMalloc->Free(pidlRoot);
}
```